# Help, bad dialog for “dir selection”, huge icon shown

Tags: 20.04, dialog

I’m using ubuntu 20.04 upgraded from 18.04, after the upgrade, many of my applications have some problem on “open and select dir” from the menu, take Rhythmbox as an example: preferences -> music, normally, it should come with a friendly view for me to select a dir, but now it just is shown as follow:

[image]

In this shit view, I cannot do anything, and not only for the Rhythmbox, some other applications works like this, such as `xmind`, is this a bug or configure conflict?

> I tried to search on Google, and didn’t get an answer:
>
> - Can any expert here help to give me some ideas on this?